# Possible Safari (desktop and mobile) bug with Canvas globalCompositeOperation source-in?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, safari, html5-canvas

I've encountered what I believe to be a bug when using drawImage in canvas and setting the globalCompositeOperation to "source-in." When I do this, drawing suddenly becomes very clunky in Safari. Is there a workaround to this? Annoyingly it works perfectly in every other browser I have tested.

I've made a demo here to show what I mean

http://codepen.io/grum/pen/VaqNLb

```
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-in";
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-atop";
```

Comment: Indeed, that sounds like a bug, and only with `drawImage`... So the solution would be to let Safari guys know about it, and one (*ugly*) workaround is to use a pattern : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WwLBqj

Comment: I've seen uglier! Will keep this in mind, seems to work well in most browsers. I've fired a bug report into the ether http://www.apple.com/feedback/safari.html. So we shall see what happens of that.

Comment: I just tried on my iPhone 4 (iOS 7) and the rotate is not applied on the pattern, this workaround has flows...